# Hidden Taxonomy field changing Static Name

Tags: 2013, rest

I used this [tutorial](http://bernd-schickerbauer.ghost.io/post-managed-meta-data-field-multi-value-with-rest/) to POST updates to a multi-value managed metadata field in my list using REST.

Basically every managed metadata column creates a hidden note column. For example **MyTags** has a hidden column called **MyTags_0**. However the internal and static name of the hidden column is a guid without hyphens.

We have a discussion list that we added some tags to and some custom code that writes the tags to that column. On Site A the internal name was `l2e10a32218249b291ea5cb2dfdfd1f5` and on Site B it was `e826a6c996c848ec8fc5adacf7f1ab73` Somehow a few days ago our code started breaking and I discovered that the hidden internal name for the column on Site B had changed to the same guid as site A.

How is this even possible?

Has anybody else ever had an internal name change? And change to match an existing column in another site collection?

Grasping at straws here to figure out what could have possibly happened.